# Executing mainframe REXXes in RDz 8.0.1 under Windows XP

Tags: rexx

We're running IBM's Rational Developer for zOS (RDz) in a Windows XP Professional environment.  Great product, but not being able to run REXXes is a big hindrance.

Searches using Bing and searchdotnet.com have not yielded any meaningful results.

Approaches we're pursuing include a) finding a plug-in to allow REXX to be used in RDz from a command prompt, b) using Menu Manager (I've found nothing useful in that direction), or c) (worst case) converting our REXXes to Java.

There are 23 more heavily used REXXes in our shop that are being considered for conversion to Java, but we'd really prefer to be able to find a plug-in, or incorporate Menu Manager to solve the problem.

Anyone else run into this, and/or have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Download a copy of [Open Object Rexx](http://www.oorexx.org/). This should do the job quite nicely.

Open Object Rexx is fully compatible with earlier versions of IBM REXX Interpreters that were not object-oriented and compatible with other Open Source Rexx interpreters currently available.

I have been using Rexx on z/os and ooRexx on a Windows platform for years. With the exception of calls for external services (eg. EXECIO) ooRexx and mainframe Rexx are 100 percent compatible. If you have used Rexx on z/os then ooRexx will look pretty much the same, but with the possibility of using oo extentions. ooRexx is a rock solid product.

ooRexx was originally an IBM commercial product (Object Rexx) but has since been put into the public domain and is maintained by the Rexx Language Association under the name Open Object Rexx (ooRexx).

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on TSO Commands in the MVS Files listing (RSE).  Open "Launch Shell".  You can then execute any REXX script that you want.

EX 'SYST.RDZ.UTILLIB(REX101)' 'PARM1 PARM2'

You can also use Menu Manager from the Preferences Menu.  It allows you to include a REXX script from the right-click menu.

Hope this helps.